# Show Git gutter after linenumbers

Tags: git, terminal-emacs, line-numbers, emacs-nox

I am using **emacs-nox** and as some of you know there are always some problems if you want to display you line numbers while also using git-gutter.

(Stuff like some extra margin jumping numbers etc.)

Now here is the thing I allways have a space between my line numbers an my code.
(I using the format `"%4d "`) so I would like to know:

**Is there a way to show git gutter after the line numbers?** Just right in that empty column. Between my Numbers and my code.

Example:

```
 7 Code
 8+Code
 9 Code
10 Code
11-Code
12 Code
```

**Stefan talked about using nlinum-mode and diff-hl instead but with those two I have similar problems:**

[image: nlinum-mode_and_diff-hl-mode_problems]

Comment: I don't understand the question: what you're asking is what I see by default (at least when using `nlinum-mode` and `diff-hl-mode`, both from GNU ELPA).

Comment: @Stefan Hi I've tried to use those but diff-hl is just pushing the line numbers aside. (See in the screenshot)

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't pay enough attention: hadn't noticed you're running Emacs inside a terminal, so diff-hl and git-gutter can't use the fringe.